# How to read/write file on client side in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to read file form local file system(client side)  in asp.net , is there any activeX require to do this or it can be done with out it

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done without extra help like an ActiveX, but I'm not aware of any ready-made solutions. Why do you want to read a local file? Most users will **not** like this approach...

What are you really trying to do ?? Isn't there another way (e.g. user uploading the file to your ASP.NET site) to achieve the result you want??

Marc

Comment: i want to compare 2 file one file in client side and the other is in server side

Comment: Well, the easiest and safest thing to do here would probably be to upload the client file to the server, and then do the comparison on the server, and send back the results of the comparison in some way

Answer (score 0):

you can use Javascript and this can be done by using FileSystemObject object

check the following link:

[File Handling at Client Side using Javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JavaScript__File_Handling.aspx)

Note:

This object is part of **Microsoft**' Scripting Engine, and thus this column is applicable only to **Microsoft Windows operating systems**.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc Said, ASP.net can't do it.

There are a few options

- Provide a [file upload](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246/EN-US) mechanism (most common, easiest)
- Use ActiveX
- Use Silverlight, at least with silverlight you can write in managed code and access the  client(instructions for [file open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28VS.95%29.aspx) and [file](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx)  [save](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/savefiledialog-api/))